# when user types size command in linux/unix, what does the result mean?

Tags: linux, unix

I've been wandering about the size of bss, data or text that I have. So I typed `size` command.

The result is

```
text data bss dec hex filename
5461 580 24 ....
```

What does the number mean? Is the unit bits, Bytes, Kilobytes or Megabytes?

In addition, how to reduce the size of bss, data, text of the file? (Not using strip command.)

Answer (score 2):

That command shows a list of the sections and their sizes in bytes found in an object file. The unit is decimal bytes, unless display of a different format was specified. And there most likely exists a man page for the size command too.

"reduce the size" - modify source code. Take things out.

Answer (score 0):

As for the part about reducing segment size, you have some leeway in *moving* parts from data to bss by not initializing them. This is only an option if the program initializes the data in another way.

You can reduce data or bss by replacing arrays with dynamically allocated memory, using malloc and friends.

Note that the bss takes no space in the executable and reducing it just for the sake of having smaller numbers reported by `size` is probably not a good idea.